# How do I unlock the Captain Gangplank skin?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the skin area for Gangplank, the Captain Gangplank skin is there, but unavailable. How do I unlock this skin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must own Gangplank and play a matchmade game.(This can range from Ranked, Normal and bot vs Ai.)

**NOTE:** this does not include custom games.

**SOURCE:**http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/special-event/gangplank-returns-and-event-end-draws-near

GreatWon comments: Will be available for 975 RP

Comment: It will also be available for purchase at 975rp.

Answer (score -1):

Join any matchmade game and play as Gangplank (It doesn't work with custom made games)

The skin will be handed out at the end of the Bilgewater event

Comment: Oh, it is handed out once the event ends?

Comment: yushhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: A bot game should actually give you the skin since it still counts as a matchmade game.

Comment: You need to play as gangplank I think?

Comment: You need to own him as well.